# Make Maven list all plugins used?

Tags: plugins, maven

How do I make Maven generate a list of all of the plugins that it recognizes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

"Recognizes" or "uses"? You can see all the plugins configured in a particular project using `mvn help:effective-pom`. A global list of all available maven plugins would probably be impossible to accurately compile. There are lists of a couple of major clusters of plugins at the [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) and at [codehaus](http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html), but maven plugins can come from anywhere.

Comment: This did not work for me (version 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT not found); however, `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom` does.

Comment: Consider to update the latter link - now is 404.